# angle Ceva's theorem

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

In triangle $ABC$,   $P$   is point such that $\angle PAB  = 42^{\circ}$, $\angle PBA = 54^{\circ}$,  $\angle PAC = 6^{\circ}$, $\angle PBC = 12^{\circ}$. Find $ \angle PCB$.

[image]

---

I found the $ \angle PCB = 42^{\circ} $  , from Geogebra

But I want to solve this problem using Synthetic or Trigonometry.

Someone solved this problem before when it was an equilateral triangle, but in this case it is difficult to solve because it is an isosceles triangle.
Link:
[Conjecture about a point inside an equilateral triangle divided by integer angles](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4063800/1127839)

---

This is the process of solving problems through drawing with @dfnu ideas.

[image]

Using regular pentagons and equilateral triangles, we can create the isosceles triangle and angles we are looking for. I think the proof will be complete when $\square ACGR $ shows an inscribed rectangle.

Comment: Diagram would be good.

Comment: Please share with us what you've tried.

Comment: I just drew and measured the angle using a protractor. It's embarrassing to even call it trial.

Comment: Those angles make me think of a regular pentagon. For example: if inside a regular pentagon you draw an equilateral triangle (sharing one side with the pentagon) at both sides you end up with two isosceles triangles of your kind.

Comment: Hint: the title of your question.

Comment: @dfnu A regular pentagon has only 36, 72, 108 degrees. Where do we find the isosceles triangle of 66 degrees?

Comment: As I said, construct the equilateral triangle internal to the pentagon and  sharing with it one side. Connect now the triangle vertex with the other vertices of the pentagon...

Comment: @dfnu With your wise suggestions, I think I can complete this problem using only the Construction. But I'm having a hard time finishing it. Would you help me?

Comment: That's interesting. I will give it a try and see if I come up with some more steps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems poorly received but I found it interesting. So I just provide a short solution.

By the trigonometric corollary of Ceva's theorem:

$$\frac{sin(54^\circ)}{sin(12^\circ)}\cdot\frac{sin(6^\circ)}{sin(42^\circ)}\cdot\frac{sin(x)}{sin(y)} = 1$$
And by the angle sum of a triangle,
$$x+y = 66^\circ$$

$$\frac{sin(x)}{sin(66^\circ - x)} = \frac{sin(12^\circ)\cdot sin(42^\circ)}{sin(54^\circ)\cdot sin(6^\circ)}$$

Now this simplifies very easily if you know the compound angle identities and the trigonometric ratios for $18^\circ$ and $30^\circ$.

$$
\frac{2sin(6^\circ)cos(6^\circ)sin(42^\circ)}{sin(6^\circ)sin(54^\circ)}
$$
$$
\frac{2sin(42^\circ)cos(6^\circ)}{cos(36^\circ)}
$$

Do note that now I multiply the fraction by $\frac{sin(24^\circ)}{sin(24^\circ)}$ since it can be observed that helps in simplifying the fraction. Then I used the product to sum identities to get it in terms of the ratios in $18^\circ$ and $30^\circ$, which are more familiar.

$$
\frac{sin(42^\circ)[sin(30^\circ) + sin(18^\circ)]}{cos(36^\circ)sin(24^\circ)}
$$

$$
\frac{sin(42^\circ)}{sin(24^\circ)}
$$

$$
\frac{sin(x)}{sin(66^\circ - x)} = \frac{sin(42^\circ)}{sin(24^\circ)}
$$
$$\fbox{x=42 degrees}$$

Comment: Your kindness will be remembered for a long time.

Comment: I'm glad to help, but next time do try to provide more context/attempts on your problems in order to get help faster.

Comment: May be you could observe that $\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(66^\circ-x)}$ is increasing for $x \in [0^\circ, 60^\circ)$ to justify the conclusion.

Comment: @jjagmath I thought that it seemed intuitive to take $x=42^\circ$ anyways, but that is clearly not rigourous. Maybe you can edit the answer to reflect the justification, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I think you are on the right track, now.
To complete the proof, note first that $\triangle APQ$ is isosceles, with $\measuredangle PQA = \measuredangle PAQ = 6^\circ$. Therefore $\triangle BPQ \cong \triangle BCQ$ by ASA criterion. This in turn implies that $\square BPCQ$ is cyclic, with two opposite equal sides, hence an isosceles trapezoid. So $PC\parallel BQ$, from which you get your result, that is $\measuredangle BCP = \measuredangle CBQ = 42^\circ$.

Comment: I am impressed by your concise explanation, and I will learn something today as well.

Comment: @Snupi In this kind of exercises it is sometimes useful to try a sort of "reverse engineering", and figure out where the construction comes from. Of course trigonometry gives you a correct relationship, which is, however, not always straightforward to solve.